# Plugin not called

Tags: imageresizer

I have a custom plugin for serving images trought LDAP `IPlugin`
 and `IVirtualImageProvider`

```
public bool IsPathVirtual(string virtualPath)
    {
        return virtualPath.StartsWith(VirtualFilesystemPrefix, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }


public bool FileExists(string virtualPath, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection queryString)
    {            
        String username = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(virtualPath);
        return IsPathVirtual(virtualPath) && HasPhoto(username);
    }
```

If i hit my server with the following url

http://localhost:7805/ad/username.png?w=100 --> 200 image served from LDAP

everything works fine
howerver without the query string the plugin is not invoked
http://localhost:7805/ad/username.png  --> 404 code not invoked

Is this the way imageresizer is suposed to work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - at least in v3.

In ImageResizer v4, you can implement `IVirtualImageProviderVpp` to make those files accessible outside of ImageResizer (i.e, without a querystring).

You alternately have the option of inheriting from [ImageResizer.Storage.BlobProviderBase](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/blobproviderbase) and overriding 2 abstract methods; this route provides the largest number of features for the lowest effort.

Comment: I have v4 installed and have written a custom plugin that derives from BlobProviderBase, but for some reason the overriden OpenAsync method is *not* being called when an image URL without a querystring is provided.

Comment: Without a querstring you are relying on your specific ASP.NET and IIS configuration to pass the request to a StaticFileHandler of some kind, which in turn will check with the VirtualPathProvider system.

Comment: I'm a bit confused - your answer above seems to imply that it is possible in v4 by implementing IVirtualImageProviderVpp. I notice that the plugin event handlers are called when there is no query string, but execution doesn't reach OpenStream unless a query string is present. For now I am adding a 'dummy' value (maxwidth) to the QueryString collection in an event handler, but it would be nicer to not have to do that ...

Comment: v4 greatly expanded the percentage of configuration situations in which this will "just work". Short of sidestepping the entire ASP.NET pipeline we can't control it all. My suggested would be to open a new question that includes the /resizer.debug diagnostics page so we can start figuring out what's interfering.